# How to send a smooth amount of packets per second on android?

Tags: android, wifi

I am trying to send a certain amount of packets per second on Android. In the end, I should be able to send 4000 packets per second over wifi at a constant rate.

I have created an app with native C++ support. In the C++ I create a UDP socket and I send packets at a certain rate using SIGALRM as a timer.

As a test, I wanted to see what was my maximum throughput for my application, so I made it so it would send as fast as possible:

```
while (!stop) {
    send(sockfd, data, dataSize, 0);
}
```

What I observed in Wireshark was that I have these "spikes" of packets received.

**Wireshark test results:**
[image: Wireshark test results]

When I run this same code on a Linux machine, I get a constant amount of packets. I'm guessing Android is being restrictive about sending so fast.

Is it possible to somehow smooth out this output? The phone I'm using is a Pixel 3 XL.

Comment: Having tried this with a co-workers phone, their phone seems to be able to send at a constant rate. This may be a Pixel 3 XL issue then?

Comment: After receiving an update and rebooting my device, it seems to work as intended and I can now send exactly 4000 packets per second. Maybe it only needed a reboot after all...